# how to change property located in .plist called 'Main nib file base name' at run time

Tags: iphone

I have already added my MainWindow.xib file name in .plist file, if i want to change it at run time by another file name MainWindow2.xib. How do we change it by code?

Answer (score 1):

You can't, since the `info.plist` is readonly on with the app bundle. You will have to do it by code.

Remove all mainwindows from the info.plist and here is an example:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    UIViewController *rootViewController = nil; 
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if (YES) { //You check here
        rootViewController = [[SomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SomeViewController" bundle:nil];
    } else {
        rootViewController = [[OtherViewContoller alloc] initWithNibName:@"OtherViewContoller" bundle:nil];
    }
    self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;        
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

The in the `main.m`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Comment: I have two TabBarControllers xib files, i think without adding its name in plist file, it will not work. so i want to change it at run time by coding. I have only two xib files having FilesOwner as UIApplication class. When application will start i want to change it as per flag changes. Can we do that?